# is it possible to disable tcp slow start with windows 2003 and iis 6

Tags: tcp, iis-6, windows-server-2003

Is it possible to disable tcp slow-start with windows 2003 and iis 6.0?

Or is it possible to up the Initial window higher than 3?

I'm basing this on a [post](http://blog.benstrong.com/2010/11/google-and-microsoft-cheat-on-slow.html) where the guy claims that google and microsoft up the window to 8 for connections to decrease page load times.

This is also related to an issue we had on our network where page loads from a remote site were 20 times slower than from a local connection.  It was eventually tracked back to a load-balancer setting; by forcing the load balancer to use the default slow-start standard the problem disapeared.

This has resulted in a bit of a pushing match between network and app development.  network is convinced that it is something that was done with the application or at the very least done by changing something on the web servers.  as you can guess i'm trying to convince them that it was a network setting in the load balancer that has caused the issue.

Comment: possible in 2008 R2 http://www.andysnotebook.com/2011/11/increasing-the-tcp-initial-congestion-window-on-windows-2008-server-r2.html

Comment: I guess you can only increase the slow start time of IIS 6.0, anyway.

Comment: What kind of load balancer has a "slow-stard standard"?